# How to force a thread to stop, python

Tags: python, multithreading

in my Proxy Project sometimes the Server process (given by teacher) ends with an error (a string beginning with 404) so I would like my thread, which had sent the requests, to stop and not to go on. I have tried with "return" or with "sys.exit()" but this seems to block everything and the Proxy stops receiving requests and creating threads. Why?

```
from socket import *
from threading import *
import sys
import colors 
import os
import time

def startPrefetch(pagesToPrefetch, mutex):
    for i in pagesToPrefetch:
        print i

def receivePage(conn, addr, request, mutex):
    HOSTSERVER = "127.0.0.1"
    SERVERPORT = 55555
    socketRequestServer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    socketRequestServer.connect((HOSTSERVER, SERVERPORT))
    socketRequestServer.send(request)

    finalResponse = ''

    while True:
        partialResponse = socketRequestServer.recv(64)
        if (not partialResponse): break
        finalResponse = finalResponse+partialResponse        

    if (finalResponse[0] == '4'):
        c = colors.colors()
        print c.ERROR + finalResponse + "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"
        print c.WHITE
        return
        #sys.exit(1)


    socketRequestServer.close()      
    conn.sendall(finalResponse)
    conn.close()

    pagesToPrefetch = []

    sourceToString = finalResponse.split(' ')
    for i in sourceToString:
        if (len(i) != 0):
            if (i[0] == '<'):
                pagesToPrefetch.append(i)

    startPrefetch(pagesToPrefetch, mutex)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    PORT = 55554

    print 'Creating socket'
    socketProxy = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    print 'bind()'
    socketProxy.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    socketProxy.bind((HOST, PORT))

    #Cache directory and mutex for it
    mutex = Semaphore(1)
    try:
        os.mkdir("cache")
    except OSError:
        print 'Created cache directory'

    while True:
        print 'Waiting for connection request'
        socketProxy.listen(1)
        conn, addr = socketProxy.accept()

        print 'Connected to ', addr

        request = conn.recv(512)        

        receiver = Thread(target = receivePage, args = (conn, addr, request, mutex))
        receiver.start()
```

Comment: `request = conn.recv(512)` is hugely broken. What if you only receive the first half of the request? And since you only have one thread that can receive the request, what happens if someone connects to you and doesn't send any request at all?

Comment: What version of python you are using? I tested the logic with 2.6 and the plain return statement works fine.

Comment: `return` is the correct way to do that. It works for me as well. Python 2.6 though, maybe it is version? But I can't see why.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Opening connection itself sends data to the server ( doesn't it? ). But you're right that the request might be to big so this is not a good idea anyway. Also it doesn't make sense to handle some of the data in one thread and the rest in other.

Comment: @freakish: It sends data to the server, but there's no guarantee you'll receive all of it "stuck together". You might just receive the first byte of the request. You have to keep calling `recv` until you have the entire request. (TCP doesn't understand application message boundaries, applications have to do that.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yeah, I forgot to say, that "it won't block the thread". :)

Comment: @freakish: You're screwed if a client opens a connection and doesn't send any data. Honestly, this code is so "broken by design" I wouldn't try to troubleshoot subtle issues, it's like rearranging deck chairs on the Titanic. Implement a design that at least could work and then fix that if needed.

Comment: @freakish: I have no idea what you mean by that. Opening a TCP connection doesn't send any data. The connection is established before there's any opportunity to send data.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think I've got a bit confused. Well, technically you can't open connection without sending data. Otherwise how would the other side know about connection? But it seems that it does not work like that with Python. I stand corrected.

Comment: Well, my teacher told us that the request can be 512 bytes max long. Not more. That's why I do conn.recv(512) because for this project I needn't care about the length of request but only about the mini html page...anyway I'm going to put in practice your suggestions and I'll see

Answer (score 1):

Using `return` is the correct way ( well, you should close connections before doing that, though ).

As David suggested this line:

```
request = conn.recv(512)
```

is probably the culprit. If the connection is made but no data is sent then the main thread will be locked. Not to mention that the request might be bigger then 512.

Move that line inside `receivePage` function ( and don't pass `request` to `Thread` constructor ) and let us know whether it works.

Comment: Well, my teacher told us that the request can be 512 bytes max long. Not more. That's why I do conn.recv(512) because for this project I needn't care about the length of request but only about the mini html page...anyway I'm going to put in practice your suggestions and I'll see

Comment: @user1576208 Well, that's not true. There is no size limit for a request other then the limit you put yourself. How would you upload files otherwise? :)